# Matlab Simbiology - changing scope of parameters from reaction to model

Tags: matlab, simulation, simulink

I'm trying to change the scope of a set of parameters of a R2016b Simbiology model from reaction to model.  The code I am using to this is as follows:

```
sbioloadproject('Comex Model 171016')
m1
m1.Parameters

for i = 1:numel(m1.Reactions) 
    p = m1.Reactions(i).KineticLaw.Parameters; 
    copyobj(p,m1) 
    delete(p)
end

m1.Parameters
```

This code is from someone with the same problem (http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/319663) and for them this worked.  However, when I apply this to my project I get the following error:

```
No method 'copyobj' with matching signature found for class 'SimBiology.Parameter'.
Error in untitled3 (line 11)
    copyobj(p,m1)
```

I think this might be a feature of the newer version of Matlab I am using - does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can work around this, perhaps an alternative to copyobj?

Thank you for your time,

Laura

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The copyobj function only works on one parameter at a time. I'm guessing you're getting this error because you have a reaction with more than one parameter. Try the following code instead:

```
sbioloadproject('Comex Model 171016')
m1
m1.Parameters

for i = 1:numel(m1.Reactions) 
    p = m1.Reactions(i).KineticLaw.Parameters; 
    for j = 1:numel(p)
        copyobj(p(j),m1) 
        delete(p(j))
    end
end

m1.Parameters
```

Comment: I do have reactions with multiple parameters.  This fixed the problem, thank you!